# How to run a javascript function during a mouseover on a div

Tags: html, onmouseover

How can I get a Javascript function to run when the user mouses over a div tag?

Here is my div tag:

```
<div id="sub1 sub2 sub3">some text</div>
```

Comment: Display "welcome" where ? In a popup, another DIV element ?

Comment: Doesn't having spaces in IDs break CSS?

Comment: @Edelcom: in Div tag itsef!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to display the welcome when you mouse over "some text".

As a message box, this will be:

```
<div id="sub1" onmouseover="javascript:alert('Welcome!');">some text</div>
```

As a tooltip, it should be:

```
<div id="sub1" title="Welcome!">some text</div>
```

As a new div, you can use:

```
<div id="sub1" onmouseover="javascript:var mydiv = document.createElement('div'); mydiv.height = 100; mydiv.width = 100; mydiv.zindex = 1000; mydiv.innerHTML = 'Welcome!'; mydiv.position = 'absolute'; mydiv.top = 0; mydiv.left = 0;">some text</div>
```

You should NEVER contain spaces in the `id` of an element.

Answer (score 15):

This is badly formed HTML.  You need to either have a single id or space separated classes.  Either way if you're new I'd look into jQuery.

```
<div id="sub1">some text</div>
```

or

```
<div class="sub1 sub2 sub3">some text</div>
```

If you had the following HTML:

```
<div id="sub1">some text</div>
<div id="welcome" style="display:none;">Some welcome message</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sub1').hover(
      function() { $('#welcome').show(); },
      function() { $('#welcome').hide(); }
    );
});
```

### Javascript

you'd probably want to include the events on your html:

```
<div id="sub1" onmouseover="showWelcome();" onmouseout="hideWelcome();">some text</div>
```

then your javascript would have these two functions

```
function showWelcome()
{
   var welcome = document.getElementById('welcome');
   welcome.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideWelcome()
{
   var welcome = document.getElementById('welcome');
   welcome.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Please note: this javascript doesn't take cross browser issues into consideration.  for this you'd need to elaborate on your code, just another reason to use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div onmouseover='alert("welcome")' id="sub1 sub2 sub3">some text</div>
```

Or something like this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/copy/of/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub1").mouseover(function() {
        $("#welcome").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Using this markup:

```
<div id="sub1">some text</div>
<div id="welcome" style="display:none;">Welcome message</div>
```

You didn't really specify if (or when) you wanted to hide the welcome message, but this would toggle hiding or showing each time you moused over the text.

Answer (score 0):

Using the title attribute:

```
<div id="sub1 sub2 sub3" title="some text on mouse over">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) way

```
<div id="sub1" title="some text on mouse over">some text</div>


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
  $("sub1").observe("mouseover", function() {
    alert(this.readAttribute("title"));
  });
//]]></script>
```

include Prototype Lib for testing

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I show hover text using JavaScript tooltip:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/wz_tooltip.js"></script>

<div class="curhand" onmouseover="this.T_WIDTH=125; return escape('Welcome')">Are you New Here?</div>
```